# determinant of a matrix A, using det(A) function in MATLAB giving error

Tags: matlab, matrix

Why do I get these errors:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

and

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

When trying to use the `det(A)` function in MATLAB.

Tried with this code:

```
A = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3]
A =

 1     2     3
 1     2     3
 1     2     3

det(A)

>> det(A)
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

matrix2 =

  -31    17
  -70   -48

det(matrix2)

Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

Comment: It's likely you've created a variable called `det`.

Comment: Surprised you didn't find the above post.  I've marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably called some variable `det`:

```
A = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3];det(A)
ans =
     0
B=[-31 17;-70 -48];det(B)
ans =
   2.6780e+03
```

both work fine. However if I overwrite `det`:

```
det = 2;
det(A)
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
det(B)
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

`det(A)` does not work, since there's no second or third element in `det`. `det(B)` does not work, since negative indices are never allowed in MATLAB.